# Creating custom report with 2 parents, 1 child object

Tags: soql, reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I need to pull a report that pulls info from 2 parent objects with the same child.

We have `opportunity` and `payment` as both parents of `GAU Allocation`. We need to access fields from `GAU Allocation`, `Payment` and `Opportunity`, however the relationships are not mapping out correctly when creating a custom report type.  In other words, GAU allocation is not an option when selecting a third object.

`Payment` is the child of opportunity, `GAU allocation` is the child of `Payment`.

[image]

I have tried the following:

- Joined report: The rows are not matching to the right record in both reports
- Cross field filter: We do not need to filter, rather just display the `GAU Allocation` field on the report

Is this possible or even with SOQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't build this report from the top-down due to SF report limitations, as you've seen.  Instead, you have to build a custom report type on GAU Allocation object **only** and add specific fields from the two parents.

Do this by clicking Edit Layouts button, and in the View section on the right sidebar, look at the picklist and choose the (Lookup Fields) option for each parent, then select the fields you want.